# Taylor's theorem for $|x|<1$ for $\sqrt{1+x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to do a Taylor expansion on $\sqrt{1+x}$ for $|x|<1$ but I'm not sure how to proceed after finding the derivatives. I'd understand how to do it if it were centered at $a$, but the $|x|<1$ has kinda thrown me. Should I be doing something with the error function? (Also I can't use the binomial theorem)

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $|x| < 1$ is an interval. What point is at the center?

Comment: @Hurkyl so I can do a Taylor expansion at 0, and then show that the radius of convergence is 1?

Answer (score 1):

The $|x|<1$ is there because your function has a singularity at $x=-1$. It is analytic in the interval $(-1,1)$, so you simply have to write down the Taylor expansion centered in zero to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use the binomial theorem, if you know how to do binomial coefficients with fractional upper index. For that you can use the definition
$$
  \binom xk=\frac {x(x-1)\ldots(x-k+1)}{k!},
$$
which is valid for $k\in\mathbf N$ and any $x$ whatsoever. Then the binomial theorem (which in this form is due to Newton) is what you would think it should be, except that it doesn't stop:
$$
  (1+x)^{1/2} = 1+\binom{1/2}1x+\binom{1/2}2x^2+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}kx^k.
$$ 
It turns out to converge for $|x|<1$, which is just what you need. To see this you need to consider how the binomial coefficients behave as $k\to\infty$. Their values are by the way the same you would get from repeated differentiation and then evaluating at $x=0$, only obtained less painfully.